# PyInstaller with Anaconda Environment Not Packaging Pip Modules

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pyinstaller

So, I'm running PyInstaller according to the [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) in a dedicated Conda environment.

Only one module wasn't available through Anaconda, so I had to download it via Pip. Once my `.spec` file packages the `.exe`, running it in the terminal throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` for only that Pip-installed module. I didn't see a place in the `.spec` file to include just that module, either.

Is there a way to forcibly include the module (plus any of its dependencies) into a `.spec` file, or is there a way to port a Pip-installed module directly to the Conda environment so that PyInstaller can spot it during packaging?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the easiest solution was just to take the module's code base and load it directly into the project.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: It's been a while, but I recall just dragging and dropping the directory containing the source code into the project's virtual environment.